# Laravel: Applying model accessors through query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a default Builder object for a model in Laravel 5.5.

I have tried using `MyModel::getQuery()` and `MyModel::toBase()` to get a default Builder result to be later chained. This was to facilitate a configurable starting point for the query. i.e. If a value is present for a where constraint, the starting point would be `MyModel::where()`. If not, then `getQuery()` or `toBase()`.

The clauses applied later may be common to either path, hence the need for a default builder.

This seems to work, but not exactly as expected. If starting with where, model accessors get applied. If starting with `getQuery()` or `toBase()`, the accessors are not applied.

Is this by design, or a bug? Is there a better way to start a query chain, than using a dummy clause such as `where('column_1', 'LIKE', '%')` or `orWhere('column_2', '')`, as it would only be a workaround and also I don't believe this would be very efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using **query()** ?

```
$model = MyModel::query();

if (example == 'test') {
    $model = $model->where('column', 0);
}

if (example2 == 'test2') {
    $model = $model->where('another_column', 'test');
}

$model = $model->get();
```

**Reference**:
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_query

Comment: Thanks. The documentation is a bit sparse. Probably should have been documented in https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent.